# Big-Oh Complexity of Multi-Term Function

Tags: math, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

One of my homework problems has me deriving the Big-Oh complexity of the function:

c^x + x(log(x))^2 + (10x)^c (where c is a constant > 1)

I know that of these three terms, c^x grows the fastest, and that leads me to believe that the complexity is simply c^x. However, I was skeptical we'd be given a question that easy to solve so I graphed just c^x (used 4 as c) versus the whole equation. As expected, the whole equation grew faster. But even after adding a large constant in front of c^x (1000*c^x), the full equation still seemed to grow faster in the long run. Am I relying too much on the graphs, or is my logic actually wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The complexity IS c^x. The reason c^x take precedence is because it is an exponential and because of how fast exponentials grow as x gets bigger. When you look at the graphs the function as a whole will of course grow faster, but this difference becomes irrelevant as x grows larger.

Example: Assume the constant c = 10. Lets explore what happens as x gets larger.

10^5 = 100 thousand = 100,000

10^10 = 10 billion = 10,000,000,000

10^100 =  10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

You get the point, exponentials grow so ridiculously fast that as x grows, the difference between c^x and the rest of the function becomes completely insignificant. Complexity theory is about finding the single term that will grow fastest, the rate of the function as a whole doesn't matter and this is why.

NOTE: sorry if this answer was to late to help with your homework